# RFID interfacing with Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, rfid, spi

I want to connect RC522 with Arduino UNO board. I have used the following table for my connect with RC522 chip.

```
SDA      10
SCK      13
MOSI     11
MISO     12
IRQ      UNUSED
GND      GND
RST      9
3.3V     3.3V
```

```cpp
#include "SPI.h" // SPI library
#include "MFRC522.h" // RFID library (https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid)
const int pinRST = 9;
const int pinSDA = 10;
MFRC522 mfrc522(pinSDA, pinRST); // Set up mfrc522 on the Arduino
void setup() {
  SPI.begin(); // open SPI connection
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Initialize Proximity Coupling Device (PCD)
  Serial.begin(230400); // open serial connection
}
void loop() {
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { // (true, if RFID tag/card is present ) PICC = Proximity Integrated Circuit Card
    if(mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { // true, if RFID tag/card was read
      Serial.print("RFID TAG ID:");
      for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; ++i) { // read id (in parts)
        Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX); // print id as hex values
        Serial.print(" "); // add space between hex blocks to increase readability
      }
      Serial.println(); // Print out of id is complete.
    }
  }
}
```

The serial monitor is showing blank on bringing RFID card.

Comment: You pin connections look invalid. Why are you connecting `SDA` which is part of the `I2C` protocol. You should be connecting `SS` (Slave Select).

Comment: @StefanBossbaly I think MFRC522 has those on the same pin.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same wiring method that we used in one of our tutorials on RFID with Arduino and MFRC522:

[image]

It's hard to tell what issue you may be having based on the information you provided. However, here are some suggestions:

- Is your serial monitor set to the baud rate 230400 to match your code?
- Have you tried adding in a delay after mfrc522.PCD_Init()? A delay of 5ms or so should suffice
- What Arduino board are you using? Perhaps a delay is also needed after serial.begin()

We wrote a tutorial expanding upon some of the basics, which may help you with your issue:

[An Introduction to RFID with Arduino](https://makersportal.com/blog/an-introduction-to-rfid-with-arduino)